# How to find the same words in two different text files and print those lines using bash?

Tags: awk, grep

I have two text files. One contain just one column of words. Hundreds of words. Just one word in every line. The second one contain a lot of columns a row.

I need to find the words from first text file which are in the second text file and print the entire line from second text file where this word is, using awk, grep or other command line program. For example:

Text file #1:

```
car
house
notebook
```

Text file #2:

```
32233: FTD laptop
24342: TGD car
2424: jdj notebook
```

Output:

```
24342: TGD car
2424: jdj notebook
```

Comment: What should your output look like if your 2nd file contains the word `carpet`? i.e. should `car` in file1 match `carpet` in file 2 or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding contents of one file into another file in unix shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059422/finding-contents-of-one-file-into-another-file-in-unix-shell-script)

Comment: Hey, @Unheilig - when you edit, try to fix embarrassing typos too.

Answer (score 16):

try this:

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```