# How can i extract duplicate lines from two text files?

Tags: python, bash

I'm working with two text files, in one of them the name ic in the middle collumn, in the other one I have only the names, I need to extract all of the collumns of the line, that contains the name mentioned in another file,
anybody has an idea how to do it?
best,
Tomek

Comment: these text file has any column delimiter ? how u will get second column from txt file?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us an example of your text files and your source code.

Comment: To be honest I haven't really done anything,
this is how the name file looks:
CHEMBL102582_entry_00018_conf_02
CHEMBL102582_entry_00018_conf_14
CHEMBL102582_entry_00018_conf_15
CHEMBL102582_entry_00018_conf_41
CHEMBL102582_entry_00018_conf_52

this is how the file from which i have to extract looks

AffCHEMBL1288585 AffCHEMBL1288585_entry_00004_conf_01.mol2 -74.8107 10000001000000100000 0.473684 
AffCHEMBL1288585 AffCHEMBL1288585_entry_00004_conf_02.mol2 -71.2064 00000001000101100000 0.611111 
AffCHEMBL1288585 AffCHEMBL1288585_entry_00004_conf_03.mol2 -68.9659 00000001000101100000 0.588235

Comment: It is quite easy to do with `awk`, and there are multiple questions/duplicates related to that. If you would accept a non pure python solution, I suggest you have a look at it. PS: don't dump text in a comment. [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25114300/edit) your answer instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find same words in two text files and print that lines ina bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434396/how-to-find-same-words-in-two-text-files-and-print-that-lines-ina-bash)

Comment: @TomekStępniewski Please edit your question and put you data there. Don't put it into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If `cols` uses `,` to separate the columns, you could use something like this in `bash`.

```
$ cat names
foo
bar
baz
$ cat cols 
1,foo,true
2,qux,false
3,bar,true
4,guux,false
$ cat names | while read name; do grep ",$name," cols; done
1,foo,true
3,bar,true
```