# Searching words in a file from dictionary bash

Tags: bash, parsing, ubuntu, search, dictionary

I see that there are many similar questions but they don't seem to help me soo much.

**Short intro**:
For studying purposes (Coursera), I have to exploit a modified version of Vigenere cypher. I am able to find some potentially good byte for the key, but then I have to perform a "brute force" on the reduced key space. 
I am saving the results in a text file, but the problem is that i'll have to parse manually the results in search for some valid english word.

**Purpose:**
I would like to compare the words in the dictionary file and the "junk" data in the TXT file until one or more matches are found.

I am not so proficient with the bash scripting, so any hint would be gladly appreciated.

Edit 1:

The input file is a 36KB file like this (only 7 char in order to keep computation short)called Perm2.txt.

```
K|frwag
K|frwfg
K|frwjg
K|frwkg
K|frwhg
K|frwng
```

I tried with grep

```
grep -Fwf /usr/share/dict/american-english Perm.txt
```

but I have too much output. I need to show only the words longer than a single or a couple of chars.

Comment: Show us a sample of your input, your desired output, what you've tried and where you're stuck. [ask].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find same words in two text files and print that lines ina bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434396/how-to-find-same-words-in-two-text-files-and-print-that-lines-ina-bash)

Comment: So `grep -E '.{3}' /usr/share/dict/american-english | grep -Fwf - Perm.txt`?

Comment: I got 
    `Binary file Perm.txt matches`
But actually no output is shown.

Any suggestion?

Comment: solved appending -a to grep.

`grep -E '.{3}' /usr/share/dict/american-english | grep -a -Fwf - TestAscii.txt`