# Check if all lines from one file are present somewhere in another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I used `file1` as a source of data for `file2` and now I need to make sure that every single line of text from `file1` occurs *somewhere* in `file2` (and find out which lines are missing, if any). It's probably important to note that while `file1` has conveniently one search term per line, the terms can occur *anywhere* in the `file2` including in the middle of a word. Also would help if the matching was case insensitive - doesn't matter if the text in `file2` is even in all caps as long as it's there.

The lines in `file1` include spaces and all sorts of other special characters like `--`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15059445/1528712

Answer (score 15):

```
if grep -Fqvf file2 file1; then
    echo $"There are lines in file1 that don’t occur in file2."
fi
```

Grep options mean:

```
-F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated fixed strings
-f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
-q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output
```

Comment: The -w flag will get you closer to matching the *exact* line, as per the question. You'll still have to assume whatever lines your matching do not contain substrings that are also words

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
awk -f a.awk file1 file2
```

where `a.awk` is

```
BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 }
NR==FNR {
    a[$0]++
    next
}
{
    for (i in a) 
        if (index($0,i)) 
            delete a[i]
}

END {
    for (i in a)
        print i
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this works perfectly with all the short test files I created but doesn't work correctly for the two big files I need it for. It also outputs some lines that ARE in `file2`.

Comment: @user2044638 Interesting. Do you have an example of the lines from `file2` that it outputs?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really pay attention as I saw some lines that I knew where in `file2` so it turns out it outputs ALL of the lines from `file1` (just in different order). As for some sample line, there really doesn't seems to be anything special about most of the lines, mostly internet links and some of them are just one word.

Comment: @user2044638 Hmm.. But it works perfectly with the short test files?

Comment: @HåkonHægland : i'd suggest 3 small modifications to your idea - `(1)` change `a[$0]++` to simply `a[$0]` :: the counter isn't necessary, since the mere act of setting hashed key into array already de-dupes it ; (2) pre-delete `a[""]` before scanning `file2`; `(3)` load `file2` all at once onto `$0` if it's less than `2 GB` or so, using `FS = RS = "^$"`.  By def. of `RS`, test items from `file1` cannot also include `\n`, so directly checking each item against full `file2` via `index($0, i)` wouldn't risk row cross-over risk, and we also gain absolutely nothing by splitting the unneeded fields

Answer (score 3):

The highest voted answer to this post -- `grep -Fqvf file2 file1` -- is not quite correct; there are a number of issues with it, all stemming from a single major issue: namely, that the direction of comparison is flipped. We are using every line in `file2` to search `file1` to make sure that all lines in `file1` are covered. This fits with how grep works and is elegant, but it doesn't actually solve the problem. I discovered this while comparing two package lists -- one the output of `pacman -Qqe`, the other a list I'd made compiling those packages into different groupings to simplify setting up a new computer. I wanted to make sure that I hadn't missed any packages in my groupings.

The first problem is major -- if `file2` contains a single empty line, the output will *always* be false (ie, it will not identify that there are missing lines). This is because the empty line in `file2` will match every line of `file1`. So with the following files, we do not correctly identify that `zsh` is missing from `file2`:

```
file1                        file2

acpi                         acpi
...                          ...
r                            r
...                          ...
yaourt                       yaourt
zsh                          
<EOF>                        <EOF>

$ grep -Fvf file2 file1
[ no output ]
```

Ok, so we can just strip empty lines, right?

```
$ grep -Fv "$(grep -ve '^&' file2)" file1
zsh
```

Great! But now we get to another problem. Let's say we remove `yaourt` from `file2`. We'd expect the output to now be

```
yaourt
zsh
```

But here's what we actually get

```
$ grep -Fv "$(grep -ve '^&' file2)" file1
zsh
```

Why is that? Well, it's the same reason that an empty line causes problems. In this case, the line `r` in `file2` is matching `yaourt` in `file1`. Removing empty lines only fixed the most egregious case of this more general problem.

Apart from the false negatives here, there are also false positives from not handling the case OP called out --

> It's probably important to note that while `file1` has conveniently one search term per line, the terms can occur anywhere in the `file2` including in the middle of a word.

So this would mean that if `ohmyzsh` is in `file2`, that would be a match for `zsh` in `file1`. But that would not happen, since we are searching `file1` for `ohmyzsh`, and obviously, `zsh` doesn't match, given it is a substring of `ohmyzsh`. This last example illustrates why searching `file1` with the lines of `file2` categorically will not work. But if we search `file2` with the lines of `file1`, we will get all the matches in `file2`, but not know if we have a match for every line of `file1`. The number of matches doesn't help, since we could have multiple matches for, say, `sh` (`zsh`, `bash`, `fish`, ...) but no matches for `acpi`.

This is all a very long way of saying that this isn't a problem that can be solved with O(1) greps. You'd need to use a loop. With a loop, the problem is trivial.

```
readarray -t terms < file1 # bash
# zsh: terms=("${(@f)$(< file1)}")

for term in "${terms[@]}"; do # I know `do` "should" be on a separate line; bite me
  grep -Fq "$term" file2 ||
    { echo "$term does not appear in file2" && break }
done
```