# how to grep exact string match across 2 files

Tags: regex, shell, grep, osx-mavericks

I've UTF-8 plain text lists of usernames, 1 per line, in `list1.txt` and `list2.txt`. Note, in case pertinent, that usernames may contain regex characters e.g. `! ^ . (` and such as well as spaces.

I want to get and save to `matches.txt` a list of all unique values occurring in *both* lists. I've little command line expertise but this almost gets me there:

```
grep -Ff list1.txt list2.txt > matches.txt
```

...but that is treating `"jdoe"` and `"jdoe III"` as a match, returning `"jdoe III"` as the matched value. This is incorrect for the task. I need the per-line pattern match to be the *whole* line, i.e. from ^ to $. I've tried adding the -x flag but that gets no matches at all (edit: see comment to accepted answer - I got the flag order wrong).

I'm on OS X 10.9.5 and I don't have to use `grep` - another command line (tool) solving the problem will do.

Comment: If the files are sorted then `comm -1 -2 list1.txt list2.txt` might do what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding contents of one file into another file in unix shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059422/finding-contents-of-one-file-into-another-file-in-unix-shell-script)

Comment: I was hoping to find a better duplicate, one which suggests `grep -Fxf`. This is a FAQ so I'm sure there is one, but I could not find it.

Comment: Well, I did spend some time looking for SO answers as I figured this is FAQ but many things were close but answered different questions (different enough to not help someone inexperienced with shell/CL tools). The most useful answer I found was this [How to grep the exact match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match), though that failed for the use case stated above.

Comment: The link at head to a suggested alternate thread *does not answer this question* (perhaps someone can delete that banner - it doesn't really help someone looking for an answer to *this* question). Likewise, the link given by tripleee doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add the `-x` flag to your `grep` query:

```sh
grep -Fxf list1.txt list2.txt > matches.txt
```

The `-x` flag will restrict matches to full line matches (each `PATTERN` becomes `^PATTERN$`).  I'm not sure why your attempt at `-x` failed.  Maybe you put it after the `-f`, which must be immediately followed by the first file?

Comment: Yes, both `-Fxf` or `-xFf` now seem to work. I'm sure I tried the three flags in all sort of order combos before posting. Oh well. What I'd missed, through inexperience, is the `f` flag *must* come last in order that the next item in the CL is the list of file names. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, grep isn't going to complain on e.g. `grep -Ffx list1.txt list2.txt` if you have a file named `x`.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` will be handy than `grep` here:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next} $0 in a' list1.txt list2.txt > matches.txt
```

`$0` is the line, `FNR` is the current line number of the current file, `NR` is the overall line number (they are only the same when you are on the first file).  `a[$0]` is a associative array (hash) whose key is the line.  `next` will ensure that further clauses (the `$0 in a`) will not run if the current clause (the fact that this is the first file) did.  `$0 in a` will be true when the current line has a value in the array `a`, thus only lines present in both will be displayed.  The order will be their order of occurence in the second file.

Comment: Yes this does work (in my example case) - even if I don't understand how! I'll wait a bit and see if a grep based answer shows up or will come back and accept this. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamKatz: Many thanks for adding explanation here. I somehow missed OP's comment and forgot to add some explanation here.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and straightforward way to do it that doesn't require one to do all sorts of crazy things with grep is as follows

```
cat list1.txt list2.txt|grep match > matches.txt
```

Not only that, but it's also easier to remember, (especially if you regularly use cat).

Comment: That command line, as stated, doesn't work. with data in `list1.txt` and `list2.txt`, the resulting `matches.txt` is empty. What 'match' does is unclear - is it a flag to grep or another command. My (OS 10.9.5) has no entry for 'match' in `man grep` nor is 'match' recognised as a command. This CL seems to answer a different question to the one posed.

Answer (score 0):

grep -Fwf file1 file2 would match word to word !!