# Read one file to search another file and print out missing lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am following the example in this post [finding contents of one file into another file in unix shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059422/finding-contents-of-one-file-into-another-file-in-unix-shell-script) but want to print out differently.

Basically file "a.txt", with the following lines:

```
alpha
0891234
beta
```

Now, the file "b.txt", with the lines:

```
Alpha
0808080
0891234
gamma
```

I would like the output of the command is:

```
alpha
beta
```

The first one is "incorrect case" and second one is "missing from b.txt". The `0808080` doesn't matter and it can be there.

This is different from using `grep -f "a.txt" "b.txt"` and print out `0891234` only.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: With your logic, `0891234` needs to be in expected output right?

Comment: If it is a match, I don't want to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep with following options:

```
grep -Fvf b.txt a.txt
```

The key is to use `-v`:

> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

When reading patterns from a file I recommend to use the `-F` option as long as you not explicitly want that patterns are treated as regular expressions.

> -F, --fixed-strings
>                 Interpret  PATTERN  as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which
>                 is to be matched.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you.